# Building release of project with QScintilla

Tags: c++, qt, qscintilla

I have project written in C++ that use Qt Framework and [QScintilla2](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro). I cannot build Release because of linker errors. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Errors:

> 1>codeditor.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   static struct QMetaObject const QsciScintillaBase::staticMetaObject"
>   (?staticMetaObject@QsciScintillaBase@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in
>   function "public: static class QMetaObject::Connection __cdecl
>   QObject::connect(class QsciScintillaBase const *,void (__thiscall QsciScintillaBase::*)(int,int,char const
>   *,int,int,int,int,int,int,int),class CodeEditor const *,void (__thiscall CodeEditor::*)(int,int,char const
>   *,int,int,int,int,int,int,int),enum Qt::ConnectionType)" (??$connect@P8QsciScintillaBase@@AEXHHPBDHHHHHHH@ZP8CodeEditor@@AEXHH0HHHHHHH@Z@QObject@@SA?AVConnection@QMetaObject@@PBVQsciScintillaBase@@P83@AEXHHPBDHHHHHHH@ZPBVCodeEditor@@P84@AEXHH1HHHHHHH@ZW4ConnectionType@Qt@@@Z)
>   1>codeditor.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   static struct QMetaObject const QsciScintilla::staticMetaObject"
>   (?staticMetaObject@QsciScintilla@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in
>   function "public: static class QMetaObject::Connection __cdecl
>   QObject::connect),void (__thiscall
>   CodeEditor::*)(int,int,class QFlags)>(class
>   QsciScintilla const *,void (__thiscall QsciScintilla::*)(int,int,class
>   QFlags),class CodeEditor const *,void
>   (__thiscall CodeEditor::*)(int,int,class QFlags),enum Qt::ConnectionType)"
>   (??$connect@P8QsciScintilla@@AEXHHV?$QFlags@W4KeyboardModifier@Qt@@@@@ZP8CodeEditor@@AEXHH0@Z@QObject@@SA?AVConnection@QMetaObject@@PBVQsciScintilla@@P83@AEXHHV?$QFlags@W4KeyboardModifier@Qt@@@@@ZPBVCodeEditor@@P85@AEXHH1@ZW4ConnectionType@Qt@@@Z)
>   1>release\JSD-V8-QT.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Comment: Show more information about your project.

Comment: @eyllanesc what info is needed?

Comment: For example as you have linked QScintilla2 to your project

Comment: @eyllanesc dynamically linked, debug build works but release doesn't work